# Check a condition for each row and create new column

Tags: python, numpy

Here is my dataframe:

```
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1    -2    -4
2     3    -5
```

I wish to have a col3 which contain:

```
1  If the value in col 1 is equal to 3
0  for all other cases
```

So, my resultant df should look like this:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     0
1    -2    -4     0
2     3    -5     1
```

I tried

```
df['col3']=np.select([(df['col1'].eq(3).all(axis=1))],[1],0)
```

Please help

Comment: `df['col3'] = df['col1'].eq(3).astype(int)`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:-

```
df['col3'] = [1 if df['col1'].iloc[i]==3 else 0 for i in range(len(df))]
```

Output:-

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     0
1    -2    -4     0
2     3    -5     1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['col3']=df['col1'].transform(lambda value: 1 if value==3 else 0)
```

explanation: transform() helps us to apply any function to a column of the data frame. Using if-else in a lambda function, solution can be obtained.